# FCM - update token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using the FCM to get the user token. I successfully save the user token in the firebase database when he first log in into the app.
I'm just wondering what to do when the token is refreshed.
I have tried some something, but I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();

    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    SharedPreferences prefsToken = getSharedPreferences(Params.IDToken, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefsToken.edit();
    edit.putString("token",token);
    edit.commit();

    sendRegistrationToServer(token);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Params.USERS).child(user.getUid()).child("token")
            .setValue(token);
    }
  }
```

In the sharedPreferencess I pass the token to the login activity and save it on the firebase databse. But then I'm afraid that it will fire up the "sendReistrationToServer" method, because it will crash because the user still got to register. I'm not sure if it is the correct way to do that. 
I thought maybe pass the token with localBroadCast or Intent.
or maybe there is better way to save the Token when its refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save it in shared Preferences and on login you can `save a boolean as logedIn in the preferences` as well, and in the `sendRegistrationToServer` you can check that boolean, if it is `true` then you can `save it in database`.

Like this

```
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
if(getSharedPreferences(Params.IDToken, MODE_PRIVATE).get("logedIn",false)){
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Params.USERS).child(user.getUid()).child("token")
        .setValue(token);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Yea just save a token for any user logged in- it is an address to an app-install on a device, not to a user's profile on an app on a device, so you can use it for multiple users on the same app (not that people ever do that)

Comment: Do this at 'first time' i.e., if your value for the token in SharedPrefs isn't null, then it's not the first time (but ofc watch you don't accidentally wipe that pref)